# Mysql complexity on select in different ways

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

In our company we have a simple ticketing system for internal requests
(such as mac registration, mail activation, and so on)
that sysman will take care of.
The basic structure is this:

**table tickets**

- uid (integer)
- issued_by (string)
- issued_on (datetime)
- ticket_type (string)

**table ticket_params**

- uid (integer)
- ticket_uid (integer, not a foreign key)
- parameter (string)
- parameter_content (string)

A ticket, with respect of the purpose, may have different parameters.
The request for mac address has `"mac_1", "mac_2", "expiry", "model" and "comment"` parameter.

We wanted a query which gives all this data. My workmate comes up with this one:

```
select tickets.uid, tickets.issued_by,tickets.issued_on,
(select parameter_content from ticket_parameters where parameter="Model" and
ticket_uid=tickets.uid) "model",
(select parameter_content from ticket_parameters where parameter="Comments"
and ticket_uid=tickets.uid) "comments",
(select parameter_content from ticket_parameters where parameter="mac_1" and
ticket_uid=tickets.uid) "mac1",
(select parameter_content from ticket_parameters where parameter="mac_2" and
ticket_uid=tickets.uid) "mac2",
(select parameter_content from ticket_parameters where parameter="Expiry"
and ticket_uid=tickets.uid) "Expiry" from tickets;
```

with some research and spent time, then told me "Look how difficult this query for a so simple task! Can you do better?"

I took the challenge and started writing the first and more easy thing that comes in my mind and this is the result:

```
select
  tickets.uid,
  tickets.issued_by,
  tickets.issued_on,
  f.parameter_content as Model,
  e.parameter_content as Comments,
  b.parameter_content as mac_1,
  d.parameter_content as mac_2,
  c.parameter_content as Expiry
from
  tickets,
  ticket_parameters as b,
  ticket_parameters as c,
  ticket_parameters as d,
  ticket_parameters as e,
  ticket_parameters as f
where
    tickets.uid=b.ticket_uid AND b.parameter='mac_1'
  AND
    c.ticket_uid=tickets.uid AND c.parameter='Expiry'
  AND
    d.ticket_uid=tickets.uid AND d.parameter='mac_2'
  AND
    e.ticket_uid=tickets.uid AND e.parameter = 'Comments'
  AND
    f.ticket_uid=tickets.uid AND f.parameter = 'Model'
  ;
```

The results are both correct BUT mine took 2 seconds to run (on a 1000 ticket-entry table), and my workmate's one took 47 seconds. At first sight no difference was so evident for me, and I've not been able to find out why the huge difference.

So, which is your opinion? And, beside that, where can I find documentation over this kind of problem?

Comment: @Enrico Carlesso - Rules of dumb - `EXPLAIN EXTENDED YOUR_SLOW_QUERY;`

Comment: have you indexed ticket_uid, tickets.uid columns ? If not put an index on those columns an measure the time again. You might have a surprise. However you should run `explain` an check if your query uses your indexes

Comment: Thanks ajreal. I really didn't know about EXPLAIN statement... Very useful! But it does not explains me very well the differrence. and @Octopus, I may try for testing, but it's a legacy database, so I'm not sure if it will be done in production! Good hint anyway.

Comment: @Enrico, re indexes - managing indexes is considered DB maintenance - if it benefits overall DB performance it should be done (it will slow down updates); normally it will be transparent so no reason why not to do it.

Comment: @Enrico, are you interested to squeeze out more performance? 2s for 1000 records might still be too much (assuming that joined table is ~10x the size).

Comment: why are you getting this in one query, isn't it more convinient to select the tickets then do a simple select from ticket_parameters for the params for the 20 tickets on the page ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The EXPLAIN EXTENDED ... will show you the differences in data access path that the queries produced.

The reason in this case are the subqueries, although mysql does a better job with them then it used to, subqueries *are* different for mysql in many aspects (and there are some inconsistencies on how mysql treats them).

**EDIT**

Here is the list of [restrictions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subquery-restrictions.html) for 5.0

Comment: +1 JOIN using indexes is almost always faster than subqueries.

Comment: @Konerak, yes, it's rarely reverse. But can still happen due to imperfections in planner.

Comment: so I've been told, hence I added the "almost always". Still, if you can show me an example, I'd be grateful :)

Comment: @Konerak, example that I have run across is when the planner can not correctly estimate the number of rows of a particular joined table (due to complex conditions not covered by index for example); in these cases it is possible to force order of execution for the query by using subqueries (this is BAD practice in long run, as the query planer can get improved across versions and is possibly addressing the problem in a wrong way - usually adding index is a better way). There are other examples (involving uncorrelated and complex subqueries with small resultset)...